# VueJS when to use id and class

Tags: javascript, vue.js

another question I had with regards to how Vue works, pardon if it's a silly question. I started from VanillaJS where an element is usually declared as such

```
<div id="testId" class="testClass">This is some test element</div>
```

where I then apply the necessary styling and javascript as follows

```
.testClass {
    border: solid red 1px;
}
```

```
document.getElementById("testId").onclick = function (){
    console.log("clicked");
}
```

However, after hopping over to VueJS, I can simply (in a good way) replace the above as follows

```
<template>
    <div class="testClass" @click="handleClick">This is some test element</div>
</template>

<script>
export default{
    methods: {
        handleClick(){ 
            console.log("clicked");
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.testClass{
    border: solid red 1px;
}
</style>
```

I noticed that I can replicate the entire example without the use of `id`.

I realized I haven't been using `id` much, is that bad? and is there any use case that I am missing out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `id` will be the unique part of the element. In `Vue`, you can bind events directly, apply css using classes. So i don't see a usecase for `id`s. And also it is not mandatory to use `id`s in the elements. It is just another way addressing the element.

Comment: They're useful if you're using  the form attribute:

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#attr-fae-form

"If a listed form-associated element has a form attribute specified, then that attribute's value must be the ID of a form element in the element's tree."

... means you can have form elements - eg, a submit button, textarea etc, outside of the <form></form>

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think that is bad. Having more id's doesn't improve site experience.

Comment: Do you think you could elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

classes are useful to categorize a set of elements that share some properties, then you can use javascript or css to change the set of elements.

An id is used to identify a component in your page, it must be unique. It is useful if you have a page with 4 sections, so each section has its own id (section1, section2, section3, section4), then you can create a link inside the page to access to each section by using an a tag like this `<a href="#section4">Go to Section 4</a>`.

I found the `id` attribute useful to find elements in the DOM, for example, for testing purposes.

Well, that's my opinion and what I know about it :D